# IIS 7.5 and ASP.NET MVC Routing

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc

I'm running an ASP.NET MVC 3 application on an IIS 7.5 server (my *development server*). When I set up my *production server* something goes wrong. Serving the **same application binaries**, using the **same web.config** file and connecting to the **same database** I get **different results**. Something must be wrong with my IIS configuration, but what?

Here's an example

I visit `http://mysite.com/An/AspNetMvc/Routed/Address/1` and everything works

I visit `http://mysite.com/An/AspNetMvc/Routed/Address/1.1` works on my development server but not on my production server which gives the following error

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed,
or is temporarily unavailable.

Module         IIS Web Core
Notification   MapRequestHandler
Handler        StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
```

Somehow the URL is served as a static file on my production server which led me to investigate my *IIS Handler Mappings*, but without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I finally solved it by doing the following.

1. Opened the *Server Manager* in Windows and navigated to *Roles* -> *Web Server (IIS)*
2. Selected *Add Role Services* and added these services that were missing on my production server (don't know which actually solved the problem)

   - *Http Logging*
   - *Request Monitor*
   - *Static Content Compression*
   - *Dynamic Content compression*

Comment: By looking at these four it seems that non of these solved it... :) Is your production server by any chance Windows Server 2008 (not R2) so it's running IIS7 and not IIS7.5?

Comment: No its 2008R2 and IIS7.5

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Doing the above steps helped him synchronize pipeline events:              http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2023146 which is why it started working.